# LineNumberReader Skips the First Line of the file

Tags: java, readline

I am reading the First 6 Lines of a text file with this code:

```
File finish = new File("C:/ABC Statements final/");
        File[] finf = finish.listFiles();
        String[] filenames1 = finish.list();
        LineNumberReader br = null;  
        PrintWriter bw = null;  
        for (int k = 0; k < filenames1.length; k++) {
            try {
            br = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("C:/ABC Statements final/" + filenames1[k])));  
            String line = br.readLine();  

            while (line != null && br.getLineNumber() <= 6 ) {   
                line = br.readLine();  
                System.err.println(line);
            }  


            } catch (Exception asd) {
                System.err.println(asd);
            }
```

My Output does not print the first Line of the file. Anyone Who Knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're eating up the first line which was `read`.

```
String line = br.readLine();  // First line was read here.

while (line != null && br.getLineNumber() <= 6 ) {   
    line = br.readLine();  // Your first line was overriden here.
    System.err.println(line);
}
```

Make your above code to look something like this:-

```
String line = null;  
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && br.getLineNumber() <= 6 ) {   // Line is read and checked - both together
    System.err.println(line);
}
```

Comment: How can I Output the Same line outside the While Loop?

Answer (score 1):

swap these two lines over

```
line = br.readLine();  
System.err.println(line);
```

so that it is like this

```
System.err.println(line);
line = br.readLine();
```

You are calling read twice before the first print.

Answer (score 1):

On line 9 your reading the the first line. This is never printed since you read the second line in the while loop before printing